# Objective-C passing a block into a block

Tags: iphone, retain, block

This is a bit of a tricky scenario.  I've been studying blocks and started implementing them for the first time, and I found myself wanting to create a "compound block".  Here's my code, roughly:

```
- (void)moveToPosition:(NSInteger)pos withVelocity:(CGFloat)vel onCompletion:(void(^)(BOOL completed))completionBlock
{

    void (^compoundBlock) (BOOL completed) = ^(BOOL completed) {
        [self unlockInteractionFromPullDownMenuTab];
        void(^innerCompletionBlock)(BOOL completed) = completionBlock;
        innerCompletionBlock(completed);
    };

    // Animate
    [UIView animateWithDuration: duration
                     animations: ^void{ [self.pullDownMenu setFrame:newFrame]; }
                     completion: compoundBlock
     ];


}
```

The goal is to take a block of code that is passed into this method, add something to it, and then pass it into an animation method call.  However, I get a bad access on the line:

```
innerCompletionBlock(completed);
```

I figure that my innerCompletionBlock is getting deallocated, but I'm not entirely sure why.  From what I understand, blocks copy everything that you throw at them, including references to self--which can create retain cycles, and which I recently learned to avoid.

Actually, I originally tried this:

```
void (^compoundBlock) (BOOL completed) = ^(BOOL completed) {
    [self unlockInteractionFromPullDownMenuTab];
    completionBlock(completed);
};
```

But I was getting the bad access, and I figured that perhaps the compoundBlock wasn't copying the completionBlock, so I explicitly declared a (block) variable inside the block and assigned it to try to get it to retain (perhaps a bit silly, but I'm running under ARC so I can't do manual retain calls).

Anyway, clearly the compoundBlock is being retained when it's passed to UIView, but I'm unsure how to retain my onCompletion/innerCompletionBlock within the compoundBlock since I'm running under ARC.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, figured it out.  Bit stupid, really.

There are various times where I was calling the method `- (void)moveToPosition:...` and passing `nil` to the `completionBlock` parameter...because I just didn't need to do anything extra at the end of the animation and only wanted the `[self unlockInteractionFromPullDownMenuTab];` that was tacked on in the compoundBlock.

Makes sense, right?

...Only if you check for nil before you call the block.  As discussed [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10473877/700471) on SO, "When you execute a block, it's important to test first if the block is nil".  Well, I learned my lesson there.

This code works:

```
// Compound completion block
void (^compoundBlock) (BOOL completed) = ^(BOOL completed) {
    [self unlockInteractionFromPullDownMenuTab];
    if (completionBlock != nil) {
        completionBlock(completed);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Blocks are created on the stack.  You need to copy `completionBlock` to the heap so you can be sure it will still be valid when you try to run it.  Just put this at the top of your method:

```
completionBlock = [completionBlock copy];
```

Note that if `completionBlock` is *already* on the heap, this just returns the same heap copy.

Comment: Hm...I appreciate your fast answer.  I have a question: is copying a block still necessary under ARC?  (It seems not.)  For the sake of argument, how exactly would I go about calling copy on the two blocks in my above example if were *not* running under ARC?  Just once on the `completionBlock` at the top of the method, but not to the `compoundBlock` because it itself would be copied internally by the UIView animation call?  Thanks.

Comment: If not under ARC, each `copy` must be balanced by a `release` or `autorelease`.  In many cases it is not necessary to `copy` a block under ARC, but there are still cases where it is necessary, so I tend to do it prophylactically.

Comment: This is Not True. He does not need to explicitly copy the block `completionBlock` in the example given, in MRC or ARC. The method does not store `completionBlock` for later use anywhere except being captured by the other block `compoundBlock`. When (and if) `compoundBlock` gets copied, it will automatically copy `completionBlock`.