# is segues cycle allowed?

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

here is the problem,
i'm working on a app with login, so i have a login viewcontroller and a main view controller, and i segue from the login to main.

and i want users can do autologin, so i will directly show the main viewcontroller if users have already login.

then the problem is logout, i want to show the login viewcontroller from mian, but i can't use the unwind segue, because if the user is autologin, the login viewcontroller may not even be loaded.

so i add a new segue from main to the login. then i'm worried about this segue cycle? is there a problem with this, like refrence cycle?

if so, how to achieve this goal? thank you~

found it, i think i should change the logic to these:
[Modal Segue Chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728463/modal-segue-chain/16721462#16721462)
seems make sense

Comment: Are you using UINavigationController or What ?

Answer (score 0):

Reverse segues are always risky for your apps, it might give warnings which may reject your app on apple code review.